# ACF Repeater field returns null value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to include a repeater field in a custom taxonomy template but it keeps returning No Posts to display. I know there are posts to display so I am baffled.
I have tried adding in `wp_reset_postdata()` but that didn't do anything, I am getting no errors.

Here is the repeater in question:

```php
        <?php if( have_rows('feature_repeater') ): ?>
 <div class="related-posts">
        <h2>You May Also Like...</h2>
    <div>

    <?php while( have_rows('feature_repeater') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('collection_image');
        $content = get_sub_field('collection_title');
        $link = get_sub_field('collection_link');

        ?>

        <div>

            <?php if( $link ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />

            <?php if( $link ): ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $content; ?>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>


        </div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>

       No Posts to Display

<?php endif; ?>
```

and here is my template:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template used for single posts and other post-types
 * that don't have a specific template.
 *
 * @package Avada
 * @subpackage Templates
 */

// Do not allow directly accessing this file.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit( 'Direct script access denied.' );
}

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="content" class="full-width" style="width: 100%;">

            <div id="post-15912" class="fusion-archive-description post-15912 avada_portfolio type-avada_portfolio status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio_category-dumfries-and-galloway inn-features-coastal-breaks inn-features-countryside-walks inn-features-cycling-holidays inn-features-dog-friendly-pubs inn-features-fine-dining inn-features-fishing-holidays inn-features-romantic-getaways">
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php
                    $portfolio_cat_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
                    $portfolio_cat_name = get_queried_object()->name;
                    ?>
                    <h1><?php echo $portfolio_cat_name; ?></h1>
                    <?php echo category_description(); ?>

                    <div class="fusion-aligncenter" style="margin-top: 20px;"><a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>/gift-vouchers/" class="fusion-button button-flat fusion-button-default-size button-default button-1 fusion-button-default-span fusion-button-default-type" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Buy <?php echo $portfolio_cat_name; ?> Gift Vouchers</a></div> 

                </div>   
               <div class="fusion-posts-container fusion-blog-layout-grid fusion-blog-layout-grid-3 isotope fusion-blog-pagination " data-pages="2" style="position: relative; height: 1384.4px;">
            <?php
                $collection_post_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'avada_portfolio', // Your Post type Name that You Registered
                    'posts_per_page' => 999,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'inn-features',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $portfolio_cat_slug
                        )
                    )
                );
                $collection_post_qry = new WP_Query($collection_post_args);

                if($collection_post_qry->have_posts()) :
                   while($collection_post_qry->have_posts()) :
                        $collection_post_qry->the_post(); 
            ?>
                   <article id="post-15912" class="fusion-post-grid  post fusion-clearfix post-15912 avada_portfolio type-avada_portfolio status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio_category-dumfries-and-galloway inn-features-coastal-breaks inn-features-countryside-walks inn-features-cycling-holidays inn-features-dog-friendly-pubs inn-features-fine-dining inn-features-fishing-holidays inn-features-romantic-getaways" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 10px;">

                    <div class="fusion-post-wrapper">
                   <div class="fusion-flexslider flexslider fusion-post-slideshow">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">

                                    <div class="fusion-image-wrapper" aria-haspopup="true"> 
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 

                                            <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>

                                            <img width="384" height="173" alt="" data-src="<?php echo $url ?>" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image lazyloaded" src="<?php echo $url ?>" draggable="false">

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>

                        <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
                        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="entry-title-link"><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            </div>


                        <div class="fusion-meta-info">
                                <div class="fusion-alignleft"> 
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fusion-read-more"> Read More </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                   </article>


            <?php
                    endwhile;
                    endif;



            ?>



    </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="fusion-aligncenter" style="margin-top: 20px;"><a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>/gift-vouchers/" class="fusion-button button-flat fusion-button-default-size button-default button-1 fusion-button-default-span fusion-button-default-type">Buy <?php echo $portfolio_cat_name; ?> Gift Vouchers</a></div> 






        <?php if( have_rows('feature_repeater') ): ?>
 <div class="related-posts">
        <h2>You May Also Like...</h2>
    <div>

    <?php while( have_rows('feature_repeater') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('collection_image');
        $content = get_sub_field('collection_title');
        $link = get_sub_field('collection_link');

        ?>

        <div>

            <?php if( $link ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />

            <?php if( $link ): ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $content; ?>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>


        </div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>

       No Posts to Display

<?php endif; ?>



</section>          
<?php do_action( 'avada_after_content' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You could do a `var_dump($link)` after the `$link = get_sub_field('collection_link');` to see if anything is being returned? First step troubleshooting option. May assist you in finding where an error may be... amateurish but it helps me. And I would put the `wp_reset_postdata()` back in.

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question last week - was having trouble with ACF. I was provided a reply. Perhaps you can take something from the answer and apply it to your issue - sorry I'm not an expert but I noticed you had not received a reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764541/correct-way-to-output-acf-generated-values-using-wp-query-and-foreach/59764901

Comment: Thank you for your reply @aliqua. I have tried that and it still hasn't worked. I think it might be to do with the fact it is a custom taxonomy but i am not sure. I am stumped.

Comment: I have custom taxonomies in mine, can you screenshot your fields and sub_fields and provide what kind of sub_fields they are (text, or select option etc) and add to your question and reply here when done.. depending on what type of sub field it is, depends on how you output. I'll try and provide some examples. By the looks of this it should be group: feature_repeater, sub_group: collection_image, collection_title, collection_link but I dont know which ones you have set to taxonomy?